# Faster way to package a folder into a file with Python

Tags: python, zip, compression, tar

I would like to package a folder into a file, I do not need compression. All alternatives I tried were slow.

I have tried:

- The `zipfile` library with `ZIP_STORED` (no compression)

```py
import zipfile
output_filename="folder.zip"
source_dir = "folder"
with zipfile.ZipFile(output_filename, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_STORED) as zipf:
       zipdir(source_dir, zipf)
```

- The `tarfile` library also using `w` to open the file for writing
  without compression

```py
import tarfile
import os

output_filename="folder.tar"
source_dir = "folder"
with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w") as tar:
  tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir))
```

But both still take ~3-5 minutes to package a folder that is ~5GB and has < 10 files in it.

I am using a Linux machine.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Are you using linux or windows machine?

Comment: Edited the question. Using Linux.

Comment: What is this system exactly? On my M1 Mac it took about two seconds to tar 10 0.5 GB files, whether I did it in Python, or used the tar command on the command line.

Comment: Just for kicks, I tried it on my slowest machine, a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. On that Python took 7:07 (mm:ss), and command-line tar took 7:06. Definitely I/O bound. Perhaps the only solution to finding a faster way is for you to find a faster machine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if it is that faster but if you are running linux you could try `tar` command:

```
import time
import os

start = time.time()

os.system("tar -cvf name.tar /path/to/directory")

end = time.time()
print("Elapsed time: %s"%(end - start,))
```

If you also need file compression you need to add `gzip` after the first command:

```
os.system("gzip name.tar")
```

Comment: Unfortunately not faster

Comment: You got any runtime diffs?

Comment: You can try using `pigz` also which is parallel implementation of gzip but I dont have personal experience so I cant help you more there. or any other multiprocessing package for that matter

Comment: Unfortunately `pigz` (and gzip for that matter) do not support folders, just single files

Comment: Runtime diffs: 
Using `os.system`: 286.68339586257935s
Using `tarfile`: 185.2227544784546s